# How to bind line to rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to create some kind of flow chart with Illustrator CS3. In other programs it is possible to bind a line or arrow to a rectangle and whenever I drag the rectangle, the binded line is adapted in a way that the line is still "connected" to the rectangle. Is that possible with Illustrator CS3? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of doing this properly in Illustrator. You'd need to use something like Visio, PowerPoint, or OpenOffice/LibreOffice Impress.

You can select the rectangle and the line's endpoint and move them together, leaving the line's other control points where they are though. Do this using the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow)

Answer (score 9):

A good workaround is to use saved selections.

Create your box or shape, and the associated line with it. Move the line below the shape and select the shape plus just the last endpoint of the line. Then choose Select > Save Selection (and name the selection).

You can then group the box and line to move them together without altering the line position. If you need to alter the line, choose the saved selection from the Select menu and then move. One end of the line will stay at it's current position.

You can save as many selections as you need then recall them at any time.

[Here's a quick video showing all this.](http://vimeo.com/37232249)