# Can I join a midpoint of a line with an endpoint of another in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape

Suppose I have two boxes joined by an arrow, as the picture shows:

[image]

I would like to be able to move each one of the boxes independently in such a way that the arrow is still joining them in exactly the same position (mid points of the sides). I have been exploring the "join nodes" tools but I have not been able to succeed in that.

A similar question can be found [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/how-to-bind-the-endpoint-of-a-line-to-a-rectangle-circle-in-illustrator), however, it has been asked for Adobe Illustrator, and not for Inkscape. Anyway, according to the answers there it seems this is a limitation of the format itself, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Luciano What was the problem with the "thanks in advance" at the end of my question?... that's never been an issue in any of the other sites of the SE network I've been into. Anyway, the "duplicate" you're pointing at is precisely the question I linked to in mine, and I'm stating why this isn't a duplicate (mainly, the answer there applies for Illustrator)

Comment: Not really a problem, just unnecessary. You can roll back the edit if you feel the need. I flagged as a duplicate while I thought it's the same question, but I retracted because it seems I found a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Diagram Connectors tool](http://goinkscape.com/create-beautiful-diagrams-in-inkscape/):

[image]

You can then choose if your connections will be orthogonal or polyline, Make connectors avoid selected objects and add curvature.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for! just one thing, do you know if it's possible to keep the line in the middle of the boxes?

Comment: I suppose it is, there are a few different options to choose, check the link. I don't have Inkscape here, I just googled and found this.